# Is "block on upstream builds transitive"?

Tags: jenkins, transitive-dependency

I've looked through the Jenkins docs, and I can't find this answer.

I'm played around with it, but my results seem to be somewhat inconsistent.

Is the "block on upstream builds" option transitive?

---

For example, suppose Project A triggers project B and project B triggers project C.

If A is running and B is triggered, B will not run until A is finished.

If A is running and C is triggered, will C wait for A to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is transitive.

From the jenkins option description:

> When this option is checked, Jenkins will prevent the project from
>   building when a dependency of this project is in the queue, or
>   building. The dependencies include the direct as well as the
>   transitive dependencies.